# Set objectId of parseObject manually

Tags: android, database, parse-platform, objectid

Recently I'm developing an android app using eclipse and I'm using parse.com online database for store and update data. Here my problem is how can I set the objectId of objects shawn in database. It seems that it is generated automatically. How can I set the objectId myself??

Comment: Can you add some more information to show your intent here? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add other column which you will consider as the id column. Make sure that you have a good reason for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative for anyone else who comes looking although I'm not sure if this would exactly answer the OP.

You can import your data using the data importer ([explained here](https://parse.com/docs/data#data-import)) on Parse.com. Here you can define your objectIds before you upload them thus retaining your original ids.

Comment: I've just tried this now. The data must be in JSON format, and not CSV, otherwise Parse will provide new objectIds and name your objectId column something else...